# Color part of string in textView in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to display some text in a TextView with @string, the problem is i cant seem to be able to change the color of part of the text. I dont want to use Java to do this as all other questions suggest, since this is the default TextView text.

I've tried using `<string name="myString"><font color="#00ff00">My String</font></string>` and `font fgcolor="#00ff00"` but they dont seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried with your given string and it is works for me. Here is an example

- Create `<TextView>` inside any layout

  `<TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/text" />`
- Create `text` string inside `strings.xml` file

  `<string name="text"><font color="#00ff00">Hello</font> <font 
     color="#FF0000">World</font></string>`
- And you can see the result

  [image]

Comment: `<TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        android:text="@string/reusltDefText"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />` and the string look like this:

` <string name="reusltDefText"><font color="#ff0000">My String!</font></string>`

Comment: I figured it out! it was a stupid mistake from me. Thank you, and sorry

Comment: @kriskotooBG It's always pleasure to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your font color is working for me, **Note** you have missed the closing tag of the string(the backslash to close the string)

```
<string name="myString"><font color="#00ff00">My String in green</font> and normal</string>
```

If this doesn't help, Whats the android version you are testing this

Comment: the missing closing tag was just a mistake here, its not in my actual code, sorry!

Here are the versions:
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 28
My testing device: android 8.1.0 API 27

Comment: What do you see in the textview? does it also show `<font>` tags? Or just black text?

Comment: unfortunately just black text

Comment: I figured it out! it was a stupid mistake from me. Thank you, and sorry

Comment: @kriskotooBG what was the issue? I still facing all text color is black, <font> tag does not work for me.

Comment: Don't set the text color in your xml